# primefaces radio button remains "checked" with jquery

Tags: jquery, primefaces, radio-button

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 with cupertino Theme :

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name> 
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

When i click on a radio button it become checked.. but if i try to un-check with jquery it remains checked.. i use a simple javascript function in the bottom link.

[screen image](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/570/screenradio.jpg)

follows the xhtml page :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>
    <title>Custom Radio Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function uncheckTest() {

      var myRadio =  $("#mF\\:vB\\:0\\:vBI\\:0\\:ITRadioGrp\\:0");
       alert("RADIO : " + myRadio.get(0).id + "     CHECKED :" + myRadio.is(':checked'));
        myRadio.removeAttr("checked");  
        myRadio.prop('checked', false);

        alert("RADIO : " + myRadio.get(0).id + "     CHECKED :" + myRadio.is(':checked'));

      }

    </script>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>

    <h:form id="mF" >

      <div>

        <ui:repeat id="vB" value="#{testBean.groupOfVB}" var="aViewBoxPrice" varStatus="vbpindex" >

          <ui:repeat id="vBI" value="#{testBean.groupOfIT}" var="aItinerary" varStatus="itiindex" >

            #{itiindex.index + 1}° group

            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{testBean.radioSelectedValue}" id="ITRadioGrp" layout="custom" >
              <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selectItems}" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>

            <ui:repeat id="vBGOF" value="#{testBean.groupOfFlights}" var="aFlight" varStatus="gofIndex">
              <p:radioButton for=":mF:vB:vBI:ITRadioGrp" itemIndex="#{gofIndex.index}"/> #{aFlight}
              <br />
            </ui:repeat>

            <br />
          </ui:repeat>

          <br />
        </ui:repeat>

        <a href="javascript:uncheckTest()">UNCHECK</a>

      </div>


    </h:form>

  </h:body>

</html>
```

I cannot understand why..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because primefaces CSS.. I had to uncheck the radio with jquery..